# How to cache remote images?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion. I need to cache remote images located in a table view. I am trying to use the Cocoapod called "JMImageCache" found here: https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache.

I cannot figure out how to use it and how to convert the objective-c code to Ruby.

*This is the Objective-C code:*

```
UIImage *image = [[JMImageCache sharedCache] imageForURL:@"http://dundermifflin.com/i/MichaelScott.png" delegate:self];
```

*I tried to convert it like this but it is wrong:*

```
image = JMImageCache.sharedCache(imageForURL:post.image_medium, delegate:self)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
image = JMImageCache.sharedCache.imageForURL(post.image_medium, delegate:self)
```

`imageForURL` is a method on `sharedCache`, `sharedCache` returns an object, but you were sending it arguments like it was a method.

Comment: I'm getting a `uninitialized constant MyController::JMImageCache (NameError)` with this. Any ideas? Added the pod, seems to have been downloaded properly by motion-cocoapods

Comment: clearing out `vendor/Pods` as suggested elsewhere fixed this for me